# Flat UI ProのRailsへのインストールで generatorを実行すると Could not find generator 'flatuipro:install' エラーになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Flat UI Proデザインフレームワークを [reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails) を使って、Rails4.2のプロジェクトにインストールしようとしています。

[参考サイト](http://joanswork.com/add-flat-ui-pro-to-rails/)を参考にFLAT-UIの適用を何度も試みているのですが
どうしてもうまくいきません

**STEP1**
Flat-UI-HTML-Developers-License.zipをダウンロードしてデスクトップに解凍
解凍後のフォルダ名はFlat UI HTML - Developers License

Flat UI HTML - Developers Licenseの初期ディレクトリ構造は

```
Flat UI HTML - Developers License/HTML/UI/Flat-UI-Pro-1.3.2
```

上記からFlat-UI-Pro-1.3.2フォルダを取り出してデスクトップに移動

対象プロジェクトデスクトップにある（ponpon）から下記の手順で手順でディレクトリを変更
1. cd
2. cd Desktop
3. cd Flat-UI-Pro-1.3.2

bower.jsonファイルが有るディレクトリに移動して、bower install

**STEP2**
下記をgemfileに追加してbundle installとbundle update

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

flatuipro:install ~/flat-ui-pro

```
maimai-no-MacBook-Air:ponpon maimai$ rails generate flatuipro:install ~/flat-ui-pro

Could not find generator 'flatuipro:install'. Maybe you meant 'formtastic:install' or 'rspec:install' or 'devise:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

上記のエラーが出てしまいます。どこの手順が間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考サイトの内容は、例ですので、ディレクトリのパス等はご自身の環境に合わせて置き換える必要があります。また、2014年の情報である為、内容が古い可能性もあります。github上のdesignmodo-flatuipro-railsのインストール手順や、Flat UI Proをダウンロードしたディレクトリ中にあるドキュメントを参照して、最新の情報に従うようにしてください。

generatorを使う所は以下のコマンドではどうでしょうか？

> bin/rails generate flatuipro:install ~/Desktop/flat-ui-pro-1.3.2

rails4.2ではプロジェクトディレクトリ以下のbinディレクトリにあるrailsコマンドを使います。
また、コマンドの最後に引き渡す＜Flat UI Proのディレクトリ＞はご自身のディレクトリ構成に合わせて指定してください。参考サイトに載っているディレクトリ例（~/flat-ui-pro）をコピペして指定しないでください。

Comment: やっとできました。ありがとうございます。